# How to compare results from Matlab ode solvers

Tags: matlab, numerical-methods, solver, differential-equations

I am solving a differential equation system with Matlab like this

```
tspan = [0 10];    
res = ode15s(@(t,x) func,tspan,x0);
```

and I have another system that is slighlty different than the one specified in `@func`, solved like

```
res2 = ode15s(@(t,x) func2,tspan,x0);
```

I would like to compare the results by calculating the difference at each time step. But since Matlab solvers are variable time step, the res.y (solutions) matrices have different number of columns. How can I make the results comparable? I tried

```
tspan = [0:0.01:10];
```

But the solvers still seem to use a variable time step. So how can I make the results comparable? Thank you in advance.

Edit: I wish to clarify, I do not need to force the solvers to take any specific steps, just need a method to interpolate the results or something. In other words, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2549238/how-do-i-force-ode45-to-take-steps-of-exactly-0-01-on-the-t-axis) does not help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Matlab's built-in spline interpolation:

```
tFine = 0:0.01:10;
resFine = interp1(res.x,res.y,tFine,'spline');
res2Fine = interp1(res2.x,res2.y,tFine,'spline');
```

Answer (score 1):

If speed is not an issue, you can solve each equation multiple times with `tspan` set to `[0 tf]`, where `tf` is the elements of `[0:0.01:10]`. This will guarantee that the last value of the solution is the one you need:

```
tsteps = [0:0.01:10]
for tf in tsteps:
    tspan = [0 tf];
    res = ode15s(@(t,x) func, tspan, x0);
    res2 = ode15s(@(t,x) func2, tspan, x0);
    % Extract whatever you need here
end
% Compare what you extracted here
```