# Change value of variable at each time step - Matlab ODE function

Tags: matlab, ode, differential-equations

I have the following system of differential equations to simulate in a `.m` file:

```
function dx = odefun(t,x)
    % display(x(1));
    % y = 5; 
    dx = [x(2); - y - 3*x(2) - 2*x(1)];
end
```

I am simulating the system running another `.m` file with the code below:

```
[t,x] = ode45(@odefun, [0 10], [0;0]);
% display(x(:,1));
plot(t,x(:,1));
```

My problem is that I want the value of `y` parameter, which happens to be the output of my system, to change in each time step while the `ode(...)` function is executing. I tried by sending another argument like this:

```
[t,x] = ode45(@odefun, [0 10], [0;0], [some_elements]);
function dx = odefun(t,x,y)
```

but I get the error: `Not enough input arguments.` Truth is that I want `y` parameter to take one value at each time step from a vector with a hundred elements. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can not "change value of variable at each time step" as you do not know what time steps the function is called at. If `y` is indeed an externally provided function given by a function table, make sure to set the maximum time step smaller than the sampling rate of it. In general read about `odeset` for setting options like parameters of the ODE function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not tested on Matlab but just to help and mainly wrapped up from https://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ode45.html#bu00_4l_sep_shared-options ODE with Time-Dependent Terms

```
function dx = odefun(t,x,y,yt)
    f = interp1(yt,y,t);
    dx = [x(2); - f - 3*x(2) - 2*x(1)];
end

%define your array (or even function) y(yt)
yt = 0.0:0.1:10.0;
y = array; % array being your array of input values. (should contain the corresponding value for 0.0:0.1:10.0

[t,x] = ode45(@(t,x) odefun(t,x,y,yt), [0.0 10.0], [0;0]);
```

or try the following if you want specific time steps included in your result :

```
[t,x] = ode45(@(t,x) odefun(t,x,y,yt), yt, [0;0]);
```

You can also do, to be sure to have your solution corresponding to 0.0:0.1:10.0,

```
x100 = interp1(t,x,yt);
```

Comment: If my y vector is a 1x100 vector, shouldn't the returned value of the ode function, the x vector, also be a 1x100 vector ? Like I have 100 input values and I get 100 output values.

Comment: There is no reason for y to be the same size (that is why we use interp1). y should only de defined on the temporal slice solved by ode45.

Comment: The fact is that I have an input of a system with 100 values and I want to take the output of the system using the differential equation for each input. Values of the input are measured each 0.1sec in a range of 0 to 10 seconds.

Comment: then you specify yt = 0:0.1:10 and y is then value of your input system. Since your already specified tspan=[0 10] everything should then run ok. I have edited the answer

Comment: Still having a 1x100 vector with input values and getting back a 41x2 matrix with output values instead of my desired 100x2. Your answer works fine but maybe I am not stating things clear. It is like this: enter an input value - take one output and so on for 100 input values - 100 output values.

Comment: There is no guarantee that ode45 should choose a specific time steps. ode45 and ode23 for that matter are based on choosing a variable time step so you will get whatever time steps they choose. If you want specific time steps you can always specify them in tspan. I have edited the answer.

Comment: Don't hesitate taking a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2549238/how-do-i-force-ode45-to-take-steps-of-exactly-0-01-on-the-t-axis

Answer (score 0):

For those interested I post here the way I finally managed to get what I want. I have a 1x100 vector representing the input to a system and I want to take back a 1x100 vector consisting of the values of the output of my system. I wanted one value as output for each value of my input.

```
global f    
t = 0.1:0.1:10.0;
f = @create_signal;

[t,x] = ode45(@odefun, t, [0;0]);
```

and the `odefun` function is like this:

```
function dx = odefun(t,x)
    global f
    m = 15;
    b = 0.2;
    k = 2;
    u = f(t);

    dx = [x(2); u/m - (b/m)*x(2) - (k/m)*x(1)];

end
```

and lastly the function that creates the values of the input:

```
function u = create_signal(t)

    u = 5*sin(t) + 10.5;

end
```

I applied the create function handle feature of MATLAB. Here is the link of mathworks help:  https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/creating-a-function-handle.html